# How to avoid number converting to the float after division in python?

Tags: python, floating-point, integer

I was doing codewars [Super Coordinate Sums](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5966ec8e62d030d8530000a7/train/python) task.

```
def super_sum(d, n):
        return int((n - 1) * d / 2) * n ** d
```

This is code that i wrote. It works for like 80% of test cases, but not for those for whom d is odd and n is even. I understand that it happens because of int rounding .5, but i don't know how to fix it. If i add type casting after multiplying:

```
def super_sum(d, n):
        return int((n - 1) * d / 2 * n ** d)
```

then float will round my answer, for example for case d = 129, n = 48 correct answer is

```
23002614121650859314295390023813765770686356346056100481311369183953951296168089825445052658029739568132862213799732717600222459651283221457666925117931656542314825567044097809172099767486211518264294073783841553301635072
```

but this func returns

```
23002614121650859002030052273414603134163824126554165855078156468894052419381420649026479480486503703631607262290068194388824847849384465650476706583375518509855234415574540876562931392494985340953010221803338452965523456
```

So can someone help me with it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you write an expression that *will* work when `d` is odd & `n` is even, even if it doesn't work for other cases?

Comment: n**d is n to the power d. It happens to be such a huge number in many cases. What is this formula meant for? here dis 129. anything to the power 129 will be a very huge number indeed

Comment: edited my comment. What is this formula meant for?

Comment: Either `n` or `n-1` is even. You can rewrite you calculation depending on the value of `n`.

Comment: Which python? python2 or python3? In python 3 integer division is `//` not `/`. In python2, normally, as in C, division of 2 integers is an integer, with operator `/`, and you have to make it a float explicitly (`float(numerator)/denominator`, or `numerator*1.0/denominator`)

Comment: @Scott Hunter no, then i would just put condition. The problem is to solve it for d odd and n even

Comment: @Suramuthu R I take the average value of the sum of the points coordinates, and multiply it by the number of these points

Comment: Neither version of `super_sum` produces the value you claim it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `// 2` last.

```
def super_sum(d, n):
    return (n - 1) * d * n ** d // 2
```

Comment: Such an obvious solution. Thanks

Answer (score -4):

Have you considered right shift one as integer rather than divide by two? The correct answer from memory might be the direction of your slash, but I can't remember rn.

```
int >> 1 = int/2
int >> 2 = int/4
int >> i = int/2^i
```

To provide copy/paste

```
int((n - 1) * d >> 1 * n ** d)
```

Comment: How would you expect this to be incorporated into the function in the question?

Comment: Showcasing the generic operation should be more useful than specific. editing to also include the solution in a copy paste manner.

Comment: @ScottHunter It's simple and straightforward solution to be applied in many places, figured it would be best to not bloat.